# Synchronously waiting for an async operation, and why does Wait() freeze the program here

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, windows-store-apps, async-await

**Preface**: I'm looking for an explanation, not just a solution. I already know the solution.

Despite having spent several days studying MSDN articles about the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP), async and await, I'm still a bit confused about some of the finer details.

I'm writing a logger for Windows Store Apps, and I want to support both asynchronous and synchronous logging. The asynchronous methods follow the TAP, the synchronous ones should hide all this, and look and work like ordinary methods.

This is the core method of asynchronous logging:

```
private async Task WriteToLogAsync(string text)
{
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("log.log",
        CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    await FileIO.AppendTextAsync(file, text,
        Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8);
}
```

Now the corresponding synchronous method...

**Version 1**:

```
private void WriteToLog(string text)
{
    Task task = WriteToLogAsync(text);
    task.Wait();
}
```

This looks correct, but it does not work. The whole program freezes forever.

**Version 2**:

Hmm.. Maybe the task was not started?

```
private void WriteToLog(string text)
{
    Task task = WriteToLogAsync(text);
    task.Start();
    task.Wait();
}
```

This throws `InvalidOperationException: Start may not be called on a promise-style task.`

**Version 3:**

Hmm.. `Task.RunSynchronously` sounds promising.

```
private void WriteToLog(string text)
{
    Task task = WriteToLogAsync(text);
    task.RunSynchronously();
}
```

This throws `InvalidOperationException: RunSynchronously may not be called on a task not bound to a delegate, such as the task returned from an asynchronous method.`

**Version 4 (the solution):**

```
private void WriteToLog(string text)
{
    var task = Task.Run(async () => { await WriteToLogAsync(text); });
    task.Wait();
}
```

This works. So, 2 and 3 are the wrong tools. But 1? What's wrong with 1 and what's the difference to 4? What makes 1 cause a freeze? Is there some problem with the task object? Is there a non-obvious deadlock?

Comment: Any luck getting an explanation elsewhere? The answers below really don't provide insight. I'm actually using .net 4.0 not 4.5/5 so I can't use some of the operations but running into the same issues.

Comment: @amadib, ver.1 and 4 were explained in [rpvided answers. Ver.2 anв 3 try to start again already started task. Post your question. It is unclear how you can have .NET 4.5 async/await issues on .NET 4.0

Comment: Version 4 is is the best option for Xamarin Forms. We tried out rest of the options and not worked and experienced deadlocks in all cases

Comment: Thanks! Version 4 worked for me. But does it still run asynchronously? I'm assuming so because the async keyword is there.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

The `await` inside your asynchronous method is trying to come back to the UI thread.

Since the UI thread is busy waiting for the entire task to complete, you have a deadlock.

Moving the async call to `Task.Run()` solves the issue.
Because the async call is now running on a thread pool thread, it doesn't try to come back to the UI thread, and everything therefore works.

Alternatively, you could call `StartAsTask().ConfigureAwait(false)` before awaiting the inner operation to make it come back to the thread pool rather than the UI thread, avoiding the deadlock entirely.

Comment: +1. Here is one more explanation -[Await, and UI, and deadlocks! Oh my!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx)

Comment: The `ConfigureAwait(false)` is the appropriate solution in this case.  Since it has no need to call the callbacks in the captured context, it shouldn't.  Being an API method it should handle it internally, rather than forcing all of the callers to move out of the UI context.

Comment: @Servy Am asking since you mentioned ConfigureAwait. I am using .net3.5 and i had to remove configure await cos it was not available in the async library i was using. How do i write my own or is there another way of awaiting my async call. Cos my method hangs too. I dont have Task But not Task.Run. This shoud probably be a question on its own.

Comment: @flexxxit: You should use `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`.

Comment: Here's the updated link: [Await, and UI, and deadlocks! Oh my!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-and-ui-and-deadlocks-oh-my/)

Comment: beware using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. Any code that is executed after this line will not be on the UI thread, So if you are trying to access or modify any UI elements after the `Wait()`, you may end up having cross thread operation exceptions

Answer (score 54):

Calling `async` code from synchronous code can be quite tricky.

I explain the [full reasons for this deadlock on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In short, there's a "context" that is saved by default at the beginning of each `await` and used to resume the method.

So if this is called in an UI context, when the `await` completes, the `async` method tries to re-enter that context to continue executing. Unfortunately, code using `Wait` (or `Result`) will block a thread in that context, so the `async` method cannot complete.

The guidelines to avoid this are:

1. Use `ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false)` as much as possible. This enables your `async` methods to continue executing without having to re-enter the context.
2. Use `async` all the way. Use `await` instead of `Result` or `Wait`.

If your method is naturally asynchronous, then [you (probably) shouldn't expose a synchronous wrapper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx).

Comment: I need to execute an Async task in a catch() which does not support `async` how would I do this and prevent a fire and forget situation.

Comment: @Zapnologica: `await` is supported in `catch` blocks as of VS2015. If you're on an older version, [you can assign the exception to a local variable and do the `await` after the catch block](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/await-in-catch-and-finally.html).

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I did

```
private void myEvent_Handler(object sender, SomeEvent e)
{
  // I dont know how many times this event will fire
  Task t = new Task(() =>
  {
    if (something == true) 
    {
        DoSomething(e);  
    }
  });
  t.RunSynchronously();
}
```

working great and not blocking UI thread

Comment: I tried this Code but not works. can I called method Synchronously with tis code ??

Answer (score 0):

With small custom synchronization context, sync function can wait for completion of async function, without creating deadlock. Here is small example for WinForms app.

```
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SyncMethod()
    End Sub

    ' waiting inside Sync method for finishing async method
    Public Sub SyncMethod()
        Dim sc As New SC
        sc.WaitForTask(AsyncMethod())
        sc.Release()
    End Sub

    Public Async Function AsyncMethod() As Task(Of Boolean)
        Await Task.Delay(1000)
        Return True
    End Function

End Class

Public Class SC
    Inherits SynchronizationContext

    Dim OldContext As SynchronizationContext
    Dim ContextThread As Thread

    Sub New()
        OldContext = SynchronizationContext.Current
        ContextThread = Thread.CurrentThread
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(Me)
    End Sub

    Dim DataAcquired As New Object
    Dim WorkWaitingCount As Long = 0
    Dim ExtProc As SendOrPostCallback
    Dim ExtProcArg As Object

    <MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)>
    Public Overrides Sub Post(d As SendOrPostCallback, state As Object)
        Interlocked.Increment(WorkWaitingCount)
        Monitor.Enter(DataAcquired)
        ExtProc = d
        ExtProcArg = state
        AwakeThread()
        Monitor.Wait(DataAcquired)
        Monitor.Exit(DataAcquired)
    End Sub

    Dim ThreadSleep As Long = 0

    Private Sub AwakeThread()
        If Interlocked.Read(ThreadSleep) > 0 Then ContextThread.Resume()
    End Sub

    Public Sub WaitForTask(Tsk As Task)
        Dim aw = Tsk.GetAwaiter

        If aw.IsCompleted Then Exit Sub

        While Interlocked.Read(WorkWaitingCount) > 0 Or aw.IsCompleted = False
            If Interlocked.Read(WorkWaitingCount) = 0 Then
                Interlocked.Increment(ThreadSleep)
                ContextThread.Suspend()
                Interlocked.Decrement(ThreadSleep)
            Else
                Interlocked.Decrement(WorkWaitingCount)
                Monitor.Enter(DataAcquired)
                Dim Proc = ExtProc
                Dim ProcArg = ExtProcArg
                Monitor.Pulse(DataAcquired)
                Monitor.Exit(DataAcquired)
                Proc(ProcArg)
            End If
        End While

    End Sub

     Public Sub Release()
         SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(OldContext)
     End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

For me actually the best working solution:

```
AsyncMethod(<params>).ConfigureAwait(true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Works also on `UI-Content` without blocking and dispatcher problems, and also from CTOR's.

Comment: You can omit `ConfigureAwait(true)` as `true` is a default parameter