# Why does awaitable code freeze indefinitely?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t = DoStuffAsync()
    t.Wait()
    Debug.Print(t.Result)
End Sub

Private Async Function DoStuffAsync() As Task(Of String)
    Await Task.Delay(2000)
    Return "Stuff"
End Function
```

I know this is not the right way to do it.  Here is what I think is probably the right way:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim t = DoStuffAsync()
    Debug.Print(Await t)
End Sub

Private Async Function DoStuffAsync() As Task(Of String)
    Await Task.Delay(2000)
    Return "Stuff"
End Function
```

I'm just wondering, though, why does it hang indefinitely on `t.Wait()` when I run the first code example?  What *exactly* is happening to the code execution at that point, i.e. what code is "running" when the thread is blocked on `t.Wait()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronously waiting for an async operation, and why does Wait() freeze the program here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485115/synchronously-waiting-for-an-async-operation-and-why-does-wait-freeze-the-pro)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's get the practical out of the way first: yes, you should be `Await`ing instead of `Wait()`ing on the result. Now on to your question of why this is happening...

In [Stephen Cleary's blog post Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), he explains how this happens. Here's his "what happens" walkthrough, modified to your methods:

1. The top-level method `Button1_Click` calls `DoStuffAsync` (within the UI context).
2. `DoStuffAsync` calls `Task.Delay` (still within the context).
3. `Task.Delay` returns an uncompleted Task, indicating the time has not yet elapsed.
4. `DoStuffAsync` awaits the `Task` returned by `Task.Delay`. The context is captured and will be used to continue running the `DoStuffAsync` method later. `DoStuffAsync` returns an uncompleted `Task`, indicating that the `DoStuffAsync` method is not complete.
5. The top-level method synchronously blocks on the `Task` returned by `DoStuffAsync`. This blocks the context thread.
6. … Eventually, the specified time will elapse and the `Delay` task will complete.
7. The continuation for `DoStuffAsync` is now ready to run, and it waits for the context to be available so it can execute in the context.
8. Deadlock. The top-level method is blocking the context thread, waiting for `DoStuffAsync` to complete, and `DoStuffAsync` is waiting for the context to be free so it can complete.

In this UI context, that also happens to be a particular thread, but this needn't be the cast. For example, in ASP.NET there's a context that can run on any thread, but only on one thread at a time. The important thing is that the context is locked, regardless of what threads it might actually run on.

Comment: Thanks for this, it was very informative.  I've been reading a lot of Stephen Cleary lately, but I hadn't come across that one yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's deadlocking. You're running `Task.Delay` on the UI thread. Then you block the UI thread waiting for `Task.Delay` to finish. You're correct: You should be `await`ing the `Task`.

Comment: Okay, so I started getting confused when I was reading over [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415646/should-i-avoid-async-void-event-handlers).  It looks like the OP's example code beneath "I can rewrite it like this:" would suffer from the same condition as my issue, but Eric Lippert said in his answer "Now, if you do need to track the task for some reason then the technique you describe is perfectly reasonable."  Where am I getting mixed up?

Comment: The `Wait` method is what's causing the problem. The question you were reading was about the use cases of `async void` methods and isn't calling `Wait`.