# Why does Task.WaitAll hang when a form is launched directly in Main()?

Tags: c#, winforms, task, message-loop

I've added a splash-screen form to a C# WinForms application to display while the application is being initialized/checking for updates. I'm using Squirrel.Windows to check for updates in Program.cs.

After adding the splash-screen, a call to Task.WaitAll in Main() never returns. This call worked as I expected before adding the splash-screen.

*What can I do to ensure that the task completes in Main() while the splash-screen is displayed in the foreground?*

**Working example:**

```
static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var mgr = new UpdateManager("xxxx"))
            {
                var task = mgr.UpdateApp();
                task.RunSynchronously();
                Task.WaitAll(task);
                Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Debug(ex.Message);
        }

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new XForm());
    }
```

**Non-working example:**

```
static void Main()
    {
        var ss = new SplashScreen();
        Application.Run(ss);
        try
        {
            using (var mgr = new UpdateManager("xxxx"))
            {
                var task = mgr.UpdateApp();
                task.RunSynchronously();
                Task.WaitAll(task);
                Console.WriteLine(task.Status);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Debug(ex.Message);
        }
        ss.Close(); 
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new XForm());
    }
```

---

I've read a bunch of SO posts describing lock-up on Task.WaitAll, but I can't find a direct explanation of the phenomena I'm seeing here i.e.
[Synchronously waiting for an async operation, and why does Wait() freeze the program here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485115/synchronously-waiting-for-an-async-operation-and-why-does-wait-freeze-the-pro/40251408?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

[How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

I did try the suggestion of calling task.RunSynchronously() but it seemed to make no difference.

Comment: `Application.Run` is a blocking call, so it won't continue into the `try` until the `ss` form closes. If you are planning on doing something like this, I would put the update code inside the `ss` form, not in the `Main` method. Really you should avoid having two `Application.Run` calls, because they set up message loops and threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem using one of two approaches.

Change to C# 7.1 and make your main method ASYNC
Right click project > Build > Advanced > C# latest Minor Version

```
static async Task Main()
{
    try
    {
        using (var mgr = new UpdateManager("xxxx"))
        {
            await mgr.UpdateApp();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Debug(ex.Message);
    }

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new XForm());
}
```

Or

If UpdateApp returns a value

use .Result

If UpdateApp does not return a value

use .Wait()

```
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        using (var mgr = new UpdateManager("xxxx"))
        {           
            mgr.UpdateApp().Wait();             
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Debug(ex.Message);
    }

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new XForm());
}
```